# Reference request: "Graded Maschke Theorem"

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I am looking for the earliest reference for the "Graded Maschke Theorem", that is:

> If $A$ is a graded algebra and if $B$ is a graded ideal which admits a complement as an ideal, then $B$ admits a complement as a graded ideal.

I found this result in [the paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1984-282-01/S0002-9947-1984-0728711-4/S0002-9947-1984-0728711-4.pdf) of Cohen and Montgomery from $1984$ (Theorem $2.3^{\shortmid}$). However I was told that there exists an earlier reference of this result.

I hope that someone can help me find it.